# bash script to identify sub-folder containing both `a.txt` and `b.txt`

Tags: bash, file, filesystems

Given a working directory that has many deeply nested folders, I want to a script that will list out the bare folder path of all sub-folders which *directly* contain both an `a.txt` file and a `b.txt` file.

File names are completely fixed, so no need to support wildcards / regexes (though obviously nice-to-know if the solution does trivially support that.)

---

For reference the next thing I'll be doing with the script is generating diffs of each `a.txt`, `b.txt` pair. But I don't expect that to be too hard once I've located each pair.

---

*When I say 'bash', technically I mean msysgit - git bash on Windows 10. But I'm hoping that those details aren't important*

Comment: `find . -type f -name '[ab].txt'` is a start, the `.` is the current working directory and maybe pipe it to `sort`

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ONLY the path of dirs that have BOTH `a.txt` AND `b.txt`.

Given

```
$: find -name '[ab].txt'
./1/3/a.txt
./1/3/b.txt
./1/a.txt
./2/b.txt
```

Try

```
shopt -s globstar # ** matches zero or more subdirs
for d in **/a.txt # match a variable depth for the loop var
do [[ -e "${d%/a.txt}/b.txt" ]] && echo "${d%/a.txt}"
done
1/3
```

[`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) lets two asterisks (`**`) stand for any number (ZERO or more) subdirectories, so

```
$: echo **/a.txt
1/3/a.txt 1/a.txt
```

this limits the search to only paths with the possibility of being correct.

```
[[ -e "${d%/a.txt}/b.txt" ]]
```

strips the known file and checks for the other one, which correctly returns only `1/3` as the lone directory with both.

It should be very efficient, and works fine if there are multiple hits.

```
$: find -name '[ab].txt'
./1/3/a.txt
./1/3/b.txt
./1/a.txt
./2/4/5/a.txt
./2/4/5/b.txt
./2/b.txt

$: for d in **/a.txt; do [[ -e "${d%/a.txt}/b.txt" ]] && echo "${d%/a.txt}"; done
1/3
2/4/5
```

Comment: If you know that one of the files occurs less often than the other, use that one as the driver for your loop to speed things up a little more. ;)

Answer (score 0):

With `find` and `bash` and a loop.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find . -type d ! -name . -exec bash -O nullglob -O extglob -c '
  for d; do
    files=("$d"/@(a|b).txt)
    if (( ${#files[*]} == 2 )); then
      echo diff "${files[0]}" "${files[1]}"
    fi
  done
' _ {} +
```

- The `.` is the current working directory.
- The `nullglob` might not be needed, it is just a habit of mine to use it.
- The `extglob` is needed because of the `@(a|b).txt` pattern, although it can be replaced with `files=("$d"/[ab].txt)` without the need for `extglob`
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.